# Calculate the number of days between two dates excluding Weekends in powerbi using calculated column

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to calculate the number of working days between two dates in PowerBI excluding the weekends.

So, I have a table called as Calendar which has the date coming from 2000-2030 and another table which has the submitted date and today's date.

Where am I going wrong in this? My Calculated field Aging is showing wrong values and I cannot Identify why this is happening.

[image: The Calculated Column and Tables]

Tried with a measure and it says single value for Submitted_Date cannot be determined.

```
Aging2 = CALCULATE(SUM('Calendar'[IfWorkDay]),DATESBETWEEN('Calendar'[Date],(AgingReport[Submitted_Date]),(AgingReport[Today's Date])))
```

Comment: Your formula seems to work fine as a calculated column. Are you trying to use it as a measure?

Comment: @AlexisOlson No, I just created a calculated column & then did summing when adding it to the table.

Comment: "showing wrong values" - needs explanation and clearer example.

Comment: @AlexisOlson :- Sounds so complex. Can you help me with this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55935908/power-bi-measure-with-concatenation-and-contains-to-find-the-matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was with the data type. They both needs to be on the same date type.

Answer (score 2):

As a Column:

```
_dc_Vol_TTR_BDays = // BusinessDays
SUMX(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR([_scCreatedDateYMD], [_scLastActiveDateYMD]),
        "Date", [_scCreatedDateYMD],
        "BDay", IF(WEEKDAY([Date],3) < 5, 1, 0)
    ),
    [BDay]
)
```

Comment: You can change the IF statement to cater to any logic for [BDay].